# Force an App to Nap

Tags: app-nap

I'm on macOS 10.12.1 on a hackintosh/iMac.

Is there a way I can force apps to nap? For example, Excel 2011 naps automatically but Excel 2016 does not nap even though it is hidden (CMD+H) and not in use. It seems most apps on my computer do not nap. It would nice to be able to force apps to nap.

Answer (score 1):

I found a great application called [App Tamer](http://www.stclairsoft.com/AppTamer/) which seems to do exactly this. You can forcefully stop an app completely when it is not active or slow it down if it uses a more than a certain amount of your CPU. However, I do not know about the effects of doing this which your device may face.

Answer (score 0):

Another App that can help you with that is [ForceNap](https://github.com/omikun/ForceNap). It is still under development, but free.